# select by !=1 scale

Tags: python, scripting

I need a script to check have my mesh XYZ Scales with !=1. Here my Sample:

```
import bpy
for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:

    if obj.scale[0] !=1 in obj.scale:
        print("found x")
        obj.select = True

    elif obj.scale[1] !=1 in obj.scale:
        print("found y")
        obj.select = True

    elif obj.scale[2] !=1 in obj.scale:
        print("found z")
        obj.select = True            

    else:
        print("no failed scales found")
        obj.select = False
```

The script does not work properly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean "*script does not work properly*" ? It is working for me

Comment: for example when bpy.ops.transform.resize a object or is it a instance from other

Comment: I see no `bpy.ops.transform.resize` in your script anywhere

Comment: i have no idea to use resize in this script. I trying other example, but he deselect my objects:

import bpy

scal = bpy.context.object.scale
vect1 = (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)

for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:

        if scal != vect1 in obj.scale:
            print(scal)
            obj.select = True
            
        else:
            print("blubb")
            obj.select = False

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your if statements are testing if a boolean value matches any of the three float values in the scale property. Comparing a boolean value to a numeric value leads to `False` matching zero values and `True` matching non-zero values.

You only need the first part of your test -

```
if obj.scale[0] != 1:
```

You can also combine the three tests as

```
if obj.scale != Vector((1.0,1.0,1.0)):
    print('This is scaled')
```

As you want to deselect the objects that aren't scaled you can cut your script down to

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector

for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    if obj.scale == Vector((1.0,1.0,1.0)):
        obj.select = False
```

Note that you are looping through selected objects so `obj.select` is already set to `True` you only need to deselect the objects you don't want.

Answer (score 2):

Following your comment (above the question), you can use Vector from mathutils library.

Vector class allows to use comparisons, to shorten the code to:

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector

unity = Vector( (1, 1, 1 ) )

#From the current selection, keeps selected objecst which scale is not unity 
for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects: obj.select = unity != obj.scale
```

In some cases you may have precision problem (float value are sometimes approximation). To avoid that, choose an 'epsilon' limit above which scale is considered to be 1.

```
epsilon = 1e-8
for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects: 
    obj.select = (unity - obj.scale).length_squared > epsilon
```

Comment: Maybe an option for using `obj.matrix_world.to_scale()` to give the "visual" scale, for a case where an object is being scaled with say a copy transform constraint.

Comment: If you want to select objects with -1 scale too, then selection should be changed to obj.select = (unity - obj.scale).length_squared > epsilon + obj.matrix_world.is_negative

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are aiming for:

```
import bpy
selected = bpy.context.selected_objects
i = 0
while i < len(selected):

    if selected[i].scale[0] != 1:
        print(selected[i].name + ' found x')
        selected[i].select = True
        i = len(selected)

    elif selected[i].scale[1] != 1:
        print(selected[i].name + ' found y')
        selected[i].select = True
        i = len(selected)

    elif selected[i].scale[2] != 1:
        print(selected[i].name + ' found z')
        selected[i].select = True
        i = len(selected)

    else:
        print('no failed scales for ' + selected[i].name)
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    i += 1
```